# Java compiling a .java using precompiled .class files

Tags: java, javac

Is it possible to use the javac to compile a .java that requires other classes without javac
returning "cannot find symbol"

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

It is possible, by using the `-classpath` option.

You'll find all the information you need about `javac` [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html).

Answer (score -5):

first compile other classless then this one

Comment: Doesn't answer the question. Doesn't address it in any way really.